# New spfx web part (1.4.1) requests WsaUpload.ashx, gets 403

Tags: spfx-webparts, debugging, workbench

I just generated a new web part using the Yeoman generator for SPFx 1.4.1, and am debugging it in the hosted workbench. We are using SP2016, On Prem.

I am seeing console logging that looks like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) [http://our-onprem-sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/WsaUpload.ashx]
```

Any suggestions on

- the source of these requests? (I didn't write them...)
- how I can make them stop?

Comment: You need to use SPFx 1.1 for SP 2016 OnPrem, SPFx 1.4.1 is supported only for SP Online and SP 2019

Comment: @GautamSheth That is simply not true. See [the release notes](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-for-SPFx-Package-Version-1.4#microsoftgenerator-sharepoint).